# How can I get a div to show an active state in a mapped component?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to have the background color of a div highlight the currently selected index.

```
    const [activeCoin, setActiveCoin] = useState(0)
    const [coinList, setCoinList] = useState([])

    
    const onCoinClicked = (index) => {
        setActiveCoin(index)
    }
    
    const renderCoinList = coinList.map((coin, index) => {

        const active = index === activeCoin ? 'active:bg-violet-700 ' : ''

        return (
            <div id='coin' className=" text-white flex flex-col justify-center  items-center m-2 rounded-lg hover:bg-sky-700 cursor-pointer" onClick={() => onCoinClicked(index)} key={coin.id}>
                <div>
                    {coin.market_cap_rank}
                </div>
                <div className='w-8 h-8 '>
                    <img src={coin.image} />
                </div>
                <div className='w-24 text-center'>
                    <p>
                        {coin.name}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
```

As you can see I set up the "active" helper function. But why doesn't it work when I try to put it into the div class name? Is it because I'm working with Tailwind?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are creating an `active` variable, but then never using it. To add the resulting class to your component, you can use a template literal in your `className` attribute and replace the quotation marks with backticks:

```
<div id='coin' className=`${active} text-white flex flex-col justify-center items-center m-2 rounded-lg hover:bg-sky-700 cursor-pointer` ... >
```

2. The `active:` prefix creates a style that will take effect only when an HTML element is "active" (e.g. a button being pressed). You can simply remove that from your string:

```
const active = index === activeCoin ? 'bg-violet-700 ' : ''
```

Comment: Yes, that was my initial attempt to have it in there "${active}text-white flex flex-col justify-center items-center m-2 rounded-lg hover:bg-sky-700 cursor-pointer". But that does not work for some reason

Comment: Did you try it after fixing both #1 and #2 above? Did you also replace the quotation marks with backticks, as needed to use template literals in your string?